# this.token under the constructor is undefinied in my methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

Some parts of code is here

```html
class API {
  constructor(token) {
    this.token = token
  }

  version = require('../package').version; //Why this exists? what was the reason behind it? Jokes aside It gives the client version.

  api = {
    version: config.version //Gives the version of Kronos API
  }

  token = this.token; //Gives the client token

  blacklists = {
    get: async function (id, div) { //dw
      let token = this.token;
      console.log(token);
      if (!id) throw new Error("[js-kronos] ID field cannot be empty");
      if (!div) throw new Error("[js-kronos] Division field cannot be empty.");
      if (div instanceof String) throw new Error("[js-kronos] division can only be a string!");
      if (id instanceof Number) id = toString(id);
      if (!["PBST", "TMS"].indexOf(div)) throw new Error(`[js-kronos] Error: ${div} is not a valid division!`);

      if (id instanceof Array) id = Array.join(",")
      got(`https://pb-kronos.dev/${div}/blacklist/checkusers?userids=${id}`, {
        headers: {
          'Access-Key': this.token,
          'Content-Type': "x-url-form-encoded"
        }
      }).then(res => {
        return JSON.parse(res.body)
      });
    }
  }
  }
```

when I insert it out of method, It works out but not in It. I'm a beginner and I don't know how to use It in methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your "this" context be changed when you call `get` function.

```
const api = new API('token_string');

const list = await api.blacklists.get();
```

Now, "this" is `blacklists` (not `api`) because `blacklists` is the caller of the `get` function. But, as you know, `token` belongs to the `api`, not `api.blacklists`.

The solution is using arrow function:

```
get: async (id, div) => { //dw
```